# How do I get Puppeteer to go to my account on Costco.com?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, web-scraping, puppeteer

Here is what I have so far but I don't understand why Costco.com keeps sitting there loading indefinitely. The click to go to my account never actually loads the next page. Any ideas on how I can get pupeteer to navigate costcobusinessdelivery.com?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.75 Safari/537.36')
  await page.goto('https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com');

  await page.click("#myaccount-t");
```

Comment: Maybe the element hasn't loaded by the time you're trying to click on it. Have you tried [`page.waitForSelector`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options)?

Comment: The page just sits loading forever. The element is always clickable though.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try few things in this case:
>
> 1. waitForSelector sounds like the one that you need:
>
>    await page.waitForSelector(#myaccount-t");
>      await page.click("#myaccount-t");
>
> [waitForSelector](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options)
>
> 2. Simply wait for one of the apis to come back after which your button becomes available/clickable by utilizing:
>
>    await page.waitForResponse('https://costco.com/example');
>      await page.click("#myaccount-t");
>
> [waitForResponse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options)
>
> 3. If not, you could also make sure it exist and then click on it:
>
>    const buttonExist = (await page.$$("#myaccount-t")).length !== 0;
>      if(buttonExist) {await page.click("#myaccount-t");};
>
> [$$](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#frameselector-1)
>
> exist will equal to **true** if exist and **false** if not.